# Sliding css and js content filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm making a jquery mobile app and have a page that needs to filter some posts.
I have the posts put in as well as the design of the filter.

You can see what it looks like below:

[image]

I've been trying to animate it so if the user presses "social" on the right, "outside" and "business" will get pushed out to the left so the filter you have selected is always in the centre, between the two dividers.

Here's an example of the sort of js I was going to use to move the divs around but just for 1 div instead of 3:

```
$(function(){
    var c=0;
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({left: ++c%2*100 }, 'fast');
    });  
});
```

The problem i was having is that if the user was to press the button on the right or left every time it would need to have an infinite number of divs sliding in and I was just wondering how to implement this.

Here's a jsfiddle with the assets I'm using (Without the jquery mobile styling)
https://jsfiddle.net/xczy346z/

EDIT: Here's also a gif of what I want to happen if you can't understand what I'm trying to make. [Example Gif](https://i.gyazo.com/809f8c2ecca288c3052174a6306919ca.gif)

Comment: Do you mean that when "outside/business" gets pushed to left there will be an empty space where "social" were before move them?

Comment: Please add the script what you have so far to your working demo as well, as it is unclear how/to which element(s) the script is attached.

Comment: @LGSon Hi sorry I might have been a bit confusing, on second glance at that js I realise it might not help with what I want it to do, I made a quick gif so you can see what I want the end result to look like. https://i.gyazo.com/809f8c2ecca288c3052174a6306919ca.gif

Comment: Ok, check my answer and I guess my way help you solve this easy.

Comment: Did my suggestion help you solving it?

Comment: Yeah It's all sorted now thanks a lot for you help. Just trying to work out how to make it so that when I click the same div a second time it reverses it. E.g. 1st click left to right, 2nd click right to left, 3rd click back to right etc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#social_one").click(function(){
        $("#side_scroll").animate({marginLeft: '-=130px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, may I suggest that you remove your dividers (`#divider_***`), both from the html and css, and add them as a pseudo on the `text_slider` like this

```
#text_slider:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 33%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Doing like this keeps the `side_scroll` clean and only the "buttons" to work with when animate.

Now you can simply just animate your `side_scroll` to right or left having the selected "button" in the middle no matter how many they will be.

Here is an [updated fiddle of yours](https://jsfiddle.net/xczy346z/6/) showing the pseudo: